# Passing immutable.js object into Ramda functions does not work - pipe function is not called

Tags: immutable.js, ramda.js

I've inherited redux store that is implemented using `immutable.js` (store object is Map).

When I try to `pipe` store through `ramda`, it does not work:

```
  import { pipe, tap } from 'ramda';

  it.only('should handle data loading', () => {
    const initialState = home(); // it returns map
    const fn = pipe(
      tap(x => {
        console.log('i am inside tap', x);
      })
    );
    console.log('this is initialState', initialState); // prints state to console correctly
    fn('wtf');          // works - tap is called
    fn(initialState);   // does not work - tap is not called
  });
```

Do you know why `fn(initialState)` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with [`tap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap).  And it seems to have been introduced in the last several versions.  The only difference between the following two snippets is that the first one uses Ramda 0.24 and the second one uses Ramda 0.26.1.  Somewhere between those, `tap` seems to have broken.  While it works with some values, it doesn't work with Immutable.

Could you [raise an issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new) for this with the Ramda project?

```js
const {Map} = immutable
const {tap, pipe, map} = ramda
const square = n => n * n;
const home = () => new Map({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3});

const fn = pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  map(square),
  tap(console.log),
);

const initialState = home();

fn(initialState);   // does not work - tap is not called
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.24.0"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/immutable@4.0.0-rc.12"></script>
```

```js
const {Map} = immutable
const {tap, pipe, map} = ramda
const square = n => n * n;
const home = () => new Map({foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3});

const fn = pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  map(square),
  tap(console.log),
);

const initialState = home();

fn(initialState);   // does not work - tap is not called
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/immutable@4.0.0-rc.12"></script>
```

Comment: Will do. Thanks!